# Determining the number of parameters in a lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I am wondering if there is a way to determine (given a variable containing a lambda) the number of parameters the lambda it contains.  The reason being, I wish to call a function conditionally dependent on the number of parameters.

What I'm looking for

```
def magic_lambda_parameter_counting_function(lambda_function):
    """Returns the number of parameters in lambda_function

    Args:
        lambda_function - A lambda of unknown number of parameters
    """
```

So I can do something like

```
def my_method(lambda_function):

    # ... 
    # (say I have variables i and element)

    parameter_count = magic_lambda_parameter_counting_function(lambda_function)

    if parameter_count == 1:
        lambda_function(i)
    elif parameter_count == 2:
        lambda_function(i, element)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm skipping the part about how to count the arguments, because I don't know how you want to consider varargs and keywords.  But this should get you started.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> foo = lambda x, y, z: x + y + z
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo)
ArgSpec(args=['x', 'y', 'z'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

It sounds like [inspect.getargspec is deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) as of Python 3 (thanks to @JeffHeaton).  The recommend solution uses [inspect.signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature). The `.parameters` member of the result contains a variety of structures depending on the arrangement of parameters to the function in question, but I'm matching my function from the Python 2 example above.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> foo = lambda x, y, z: x + y + z
>>> inspect.signature(foo).parameters
mappingproxy(OrderedDict([('x', <Parameter "x">), ('y', <Parameter "y">), ('z', <Parameter "z">)]))
```

Comment: looks like inspect.getargspec is deprecated, it is suggested to use inspect.signature

Answer (score 63):

Lambdas are functions like any other.  The argument count is stored in `func.__code__.co_argcount`.

```
>>> foo = lambda x, y=2: x+y
>>> foo.__code__.co_argcount
2
>>> foo = lambda x, y=2, z=3: x+y+z
>>> foo.__code__.co_argcount
3
```

Comment: +1 Great answer -- wish I could accept two answers.  This is in fact how inspect.py does it (looked up the source).

Comment: But using `inspect` you get the "portable" functionality, seeing how the attribute's name changed from Python 2 to Python 3.

Comment: This answer is great because it has almost zero computational compared to the inspect approach which needs to load the module.

Answer (score 10):

From the documentation on [callable types](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), the `func_code` attribute of functions contains a code object, and from the inspect module documentation on [code objects](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) there is a `co_argcount` member that contains the number of arguments (not including `*` or `**` args).

So the best way to get this information from a lambda function (or any function) is to use `func.func_code.co_argcount`:

```
>>> foo = lambda a, b, *args, **kwargs: None
>>> foo.func_code.co_argcount
2
```