# How to find attributes of a python user-defined class?

Tags: python, object

Please see the following example code, which is in a file, say

**`classattr.py`**

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2

    def somemethod(self):
        return "This is returned when I do Base.__dict__"

class ChildOfBaseClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3, param4):
        super(ChildOfBaseClass, self).__init__(param1, param2)
        self.param3 = param3
        self.param4 = param4

    def somemethod(self, param3, param4):
        a = param3 + param4
        return a
```

I want to get all the attributes (I am assuming that `param1`, `param2` etc. are called attributes) of the classes before I create any instance. Command `dir(classattr.BaseClass)` does not list `param1` and `param2`. It, however, does return the method `somemethod`.

I am trying to get the attributes for the following reason: The module **`classattr`** is imported in another file where the name of the class, either `classattr.BaseClass` or `classattr.ChildOfBaseClass` is provided as an input to some function. I want to determine which one it is during the runtime and then use appropriate inputs (either `param1` and `param2` if the former, or all the parameters `param1` to `param4` if the latter) when creating the instance. The way I was thinking of doing this is to check whether the class has `param3` as an attribute and then creating the instance with correct inputs. Is there another better way to check? Another way is to have `param3` and `param4` as inputs in `BaseClass` even if they do not do anything and then always create instance with all four parameters as inputs. But that does not seems appropriate way of doing things.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't know what instance attributes a class will give to its instances, because they don't exist before an instance is created.

However, if what you want is to know what parameters you need to pass when instantiating the class, you can inspect the call signature of the class's `__init__` method to see what parameters it accepts.  See [Determining the number of parameters in a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865325/determining-the-number-of-parameters-in-a-lambda) for some information about getting the call signature.

Note that there's no inherent relationship between instance attributes and `__init__` parameters.  You could have a class like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.someAttr = 10
```

. . . which defines an instance attribute without receiving any parameters.  (Or vice versa, a class that accepts parameters but doesn't use them to create instance attributes.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. How do I apply the method stated in the link you gave, to the __init__ function in my case. For example, I tried `inspect.getargspec(classattr.BaseClass). I get an error saying that BaseClass is not a function. Thanks!

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong.  A class is not the same thing as its `__init__` method.  You must call `inspect.getargspec(classattr.BaseClass.__init__)`.

Comment: Great. After I read the error I tried inspect.getargspec(classattr.BaseClass.__init__()) and that was giving an error too. Your solution works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real way to get the names of attributes that are only assigned after the object is created, such as those defined in `__init__()`, without actually creating the instance. The `__init__()` method can do anything at all, and an instance might have been even further amended by code that's not even in the class. So if you want to know what attributes an instance has, you need an instance.

Answer (score 1):

BrenBarn's answer directs you to some ideas that might help you solve your problem. I just thought I'd add some notes on terminology.

In Python, the *attributes* of an object are the named values stored within it (and an object is pretty much nothing more and nothing less than "a thing that has attributes"). They are retrieved with the `dotted.name` syntax.

Classes in Python are objects. They therefore have attributes. The most important ones are all the names that you defined in the `class` block (including the methods), which become attributes of the class object. So when you ask about the *attributes* of a class, it sounds like you're wanting to retrieve the attributes of the **class object itself**, which is not actually the case.

Indeed one of the things `dir(classattr.BaseClass)` is doing is looking up the attributes of `classattr.BaseClass`, where it finds the `somemethod` attribute, but does not find `param1` or `param2` because they are *not* attributes of the **class object** `BaseClass`; they (will be) attributes of *instances* of `BaseClass` once those instances have been created and initialised.

But what you *really* seem to be asking about is how to find out the call signature of the `__init__` method of a given class. As noted by BrenBarn, although classes are *often* written to simply directly initialise their instances' attributes from the arguments to `__init__`, there is absolutely no guarantee that this is the case. But if your purpose is just to know what information to pass to a class in order to create an instance, then you don't need to know (and shouldn't care) what will end up being stored as attributes, but rather just what are the required parameters to the `__init__` method.

Comment: Is there a way to find required parameters of the __init__ method? Thanks.

Comment: @Curious2learn BrenBarn's answer contains a link that has information about getting the call signature of functions.