# how do I find out how many arguments a lambda function needs

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares

I'm trying to create a function that will do a least squares fit based on a passed in lambda function.  I want to create an array of zeroes of length equal to that of the number of arguments taken by the lambda function for the initial guess to the lambda function.  so if its linear I want [0,0] and for quadratic I want [0,0,0].

```
#polynomial functions
linear = lambda p, x: p[0] * x + p[1]
quadratic = lambda p, x: p[0] * x**2 + p[1] * x + p[2]
cubic = lambda p, x: p[0] * x**3 + p[1] * x**2 + p[2] * x + p[3]

#polynomial functions forced through 0
linear_zero = lambda p, x: p[0] * x 
quadratic_zero = lambda p, x: p[0] * x**2 + p[1] * x 
cubic_zero = lambda p, x: p[0] * x**3 + p[1] * x**2 + p[2] * x

def linFit(x, y,fitfunc):
    errfunc = lambda p, x, y: fitfunc(p, x) - y
```

Here I want to create a array of zeros. But at this point p isn't defined. so len(p) does not work.

```
    init_p = np.array(zeros(len(p)))  #bundle initial values in initial parameters

    p1, success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, init_p.copy(), args = (x, y))
    return p1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining the number of parameters in a lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865325/determining-the-number-of-parameters-in-a-lambda)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

under python >= 2.7:

```
>>> l = lambda a, b: None
>>> l.func_code.co_argcount
2
```

or under 2.6:

```
>>> l.__code__.co_argcount
2
```

Comment: hmm.  I guess another problem is that I'm using an array as one of my arguments.  So this will give me back 2 for all of my lambda functions, because the array only counts as 1 argument

Comment: @richmb - sounds like a design problem.

Comment: I solved this by using touples for the function declarations.  added a length parameter.

Answer (score 2):

by looking at it's code object `__code__`:

```
>>> p=lambda x,y:x+y
>>> len(p.__code__.co_varnames)
2
>>> p.__code__.co_varnames
('x', 'y')
```